# System.getenv() not finding environment variables on Eclipse (Mac)

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I tried doing everything but my environment variables are just not recognized on Mac.

The image is attached below.

[image]

```
System.getenv("TEST_LOGIN_DBKEY") returns null although the variable is present.
```

Comment: How did you add the environment variables?

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow. Please do not post pictures of your code. Please post the text itself in your post. Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better understand of what is expected in a question. Please also go through the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `launchctl` to tell e.g., Eclipse about these variables.

```
launchctl setenv TEST_LOGIN_DBKEY key-goes-here
```

You can automate this and extend it to all your bash environment variables by placing the following at the bottom of your `~./bashrc`:

```
set | sed 's/=/ /' | xargs launchctl setenv
```

The `set` prints the list of defined variables, the `sed` replaces equals signs in the `set` output with spaces, as that's how `launchctl` expects the variables. Finally, `xargs` passed each variable to `launchctl`'s `set env` command.